# How can I convert this to string?

Tags: c#

I would like to add 2 to each char from a 5 char string. I can add 2 to each char  but it produces numbers i.e its ASCII values instead of characters.I would like to convert them to string.

I'm a beginner to c# and probably won't understand anything complex, i'd appreciate any simple replies. I'm not permitted to use arrays either, nor foreach, I need to be able to simply add 2 to each char from a FIVE letter string and print the RESULT of the new "word" that will be created from the plus 2 encryption.

```
word = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write(word.ElementAt(0) + 2);
Console.Write(word.ElementAt(1) + 2);
Console.Write(word.ElementAt(2) + 2);
Console.Write(word.ElementAt(3) + 2);
Console.Write(word.ElementAt(4) + 2);
```

Comment: Tell us what `word` is and where it comes from. Tell us why you “need to add 2 to each char”.

Comment: I updated the description to hopefully give more useful info.

Comment: What do you want “z” converted to?

Comment: In .NET (as well as VB4/5/6/A/Script, Java, JavaScript, ...) the text datatypes (string, char, ...) contain UTF-16 code units, one or two of which encode a [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) codepoint. So, in addition to what you want "z" convert to, what do you want "" converted to?

Comment: I don't know what "z" is as I never inputted that. But I simply need each char of the 5 letter STRING inputted by the END USER to be added by 2 and to print a STRING not their ASCII values. WITHOUT foreach or arrays etc. I need this to be in more basic forms, regardless if it takes me long to code.

Comment: So, the input is limited to the [Basic Latin letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_basic_Latin_alphabet) of the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/char'ts/nameslist/index.html) block? Are you sure you want 'z' mapped to '|'?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to do, but here is a solution: https://dotnetfiddle.net/w9QeHo

```
string word = "Hello";
Console.Write((char)(word.ElementAt(0) + 2));
Console.Write((char)(word.ElementAt(1) + 2));
Console.Write((char)(word.ElementAt(2) + 2));
Console.Write((char)(word.ElementAt(3) + 2));
Console.Write((char)(word.ElementAt(4) + 2));
word = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: would I be able to lets say create char variables with no values and simply set them to equate to word.ElementAt(whatever position) and go on from there? would this still convert?

Comment: The problem with using `ElementAt` and an index is that you need to know the length of the input.  If someone changed _"Hello"_ to _"Hello There"_, you'd have to write more code.  A better solution is to iterate through the characters in the input (as @Nish26 and I do).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code that will work :

```
string word = "Hello";
string result = string.Empty;
foreach(char c in word) //loop through each character of word
{
    result +=  (char)(c + 2);  //Add 2 to character and append it to result after converting back to character
}

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

I changed it a  bit so that it is not limited to only 5 character words.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna dive into Linq you could do this in one line:

```
Console.WriteLine(new String(word.Select(x => (char)(x + 2)).ToArray()));
```

A string in C# is basically a collection of `char`, so we are selecting each char, modifying it by `+2`, then taking the resulting collection and turning it into an array which is what the constructor for `String` accepts.

Its not the most beginner friendly but its something to demonstrate the power of Linq.

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/s0KQig)

Comment: I tried to mix LINQ and a StringBuilder together and gave up (setting for a foreach loop).

Answer (score 0):

Or, using a `StringBuilder` (which will be much more efficient if the input string is long):

```
 var word = "Hello";
 var buffer = new StringBuilder(word.Length);
 foreach (var c in word)
 {
     buffer.Append((char) (c + 2));
 }
```

The result can be found with a call to `buffer.ToString()`:

```
Console.WriteLine(buffer.ToString());
```

Concatenating an arbitrarily long set of strings is best done with a `StringBuilder`